# LINQ INNER JOIN with 2 inner joins

Tags: linq

How do I make the following into LINQ:

```
    SELECT T.fn, T.ln, T.Phone
    FROM PG P 
    LEFT JOIN BUD B ON P.PgID = B.PgID
    LEFT JOIN TERR T ON B.Tir= T.Tir
```

I tried the following but did not work:

```
    var result = (from pr in db.PG
                  join b in db.BUD on pr.PgID equals b.PgID into  tl_b
                  join tr in db.TERR on b.Tir equals tr.Tirr into tl_tr                                                       
                  from b in tl_b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  from tr in tl_tr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new {
                   tr.fn, tr.ln,tr.Phone

                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the into statements, don't re-use names (b, tr)

```
var result = (from pr in db.PG
              join b in db.BUD on pr.PgID equals b.PgID
              join tr in db.TERR on b.Tir equals tr.Tirr
              from b2 in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
              from tr2 in tr.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                 tr2.fn,
                 tr2.ln,
                 tr2.Phone
             });
```

Try with this, but I won't be surprised if you get a NullReference exception.
Let us know.

Comment: OK- Thanks. Let me try it out. It may be a bit later today as I got some other fires that came up